Trying to get trending revenue for clients active in a selected quarter
I have a dataset that essentially organizes clients by active/inactive status by quarter, along with their rolling 12 revenue. Here's what I'm trying to do with it. Let's say there are 993 active clients in Q1 2020. If I select Q1 2020, I want to see revenue for those 993 clients in a trending graph through 2020, 2021, 2022, and 2023, regardless of whether they were active in any other quarter. Essentially, the filter would create a static active client list for that quarter and show me the total revenue of all those clients moving forward. I've tried to create a second date table, but I'm not really sure how to proceed with this issue.
I've attached sample data below.
Sample Data
